# how to use 受欢迎 in the past tense?

Tags: grammar

I'm a bit confused on how to use A受的欢迎  in the past tense. 
Would you say 
"可是这家餐厅已经受了所有外国人的欢迎。
or
这家餐厅已经收到了所有外国人的欢迎？

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Was confused at first thinking you meant the restaurant was no longer as welcoming to foreigners as it used to be. I might create a separate question for that, as 受欢迎 seems to potentially work in both ways.

Answer (score 6):

you can also use “从前”，“过去”，“曾经” to indicate the past time, but both imply that the current situation is opposite of the previous.

This restaurant used to be popular among foreigners(,but now is not that popular).

- 这家餐厅从前很受外国人的欢迎（，但现在已经不那么受欢迎了）。
- 这家餐厅过去很受外国人的欢迎（，但现在已经不那么受欢迎了）。
- 这家餐厅曾经很受外国人的欢迎（，但现在已经不那么受欢迎了）。

if you want to use "已经" to express "have been", you can say:

This restaurant has been (very) popular among foreigners.

- 这家餐厅已经很受外国人的欢迎了。

Comment: What about translating "have been" as "... 向來都 ..."

Answer (score 1):

Simply use "以前", if the restaurant is not as good as before:

這家餐廳以前很受外國人(/食客/遊客)歡迎.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply say "這家餐廳受到了外國人的歡迎", then we understand that this restaurant is possibly still popular for foreigners.

But if you say instead "這家餐聽曾經受到外國人的歡迎", then we know clearly that the restaurant now is not as popular as it was.

Answer (score 0):

Besides willyang's words, my additions：

"受欢迎" looks like a past tense however most of time **it's just a State**. So sometimes you don't need to care much about when it happens——Like that in English——Welcomed, just means "the state of someone that is welcomed".

For example:

You are welcomed here（你来这里很欢迎。）